# Different in transfering data between Pipe and Serialization in Java and C?

Tags: java, c, serialization, pipe

I am studying about the Interprocess Communication Methods in the course Operating System Concept.

I don't really understand the mechanism in transferring data. In the case of pipe method, a conduit will be created between 2 process to transfer byte streams , right?

And how about Serialization?
I know Serialization is the method to convert an object into byte stream to transfer and we can rebuild the object when it reached the destination.

So in which case we use Serialzation or Pipe to transfer data?
What is the advantages and the disadvantages between them?

Can anyone explain to me a very deep mechanism in transferring data of these methods? And are these mechanisms different between Java and C? , or it is the same?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges here. Serialization is a way of encoding and decoding data. Pipes and sockets are ways of moving it about. They are not comparable, or competitive.

Comment: Thank you EJP, i was very confused with these terminologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic types of pipe in UNIX/Linux: a named pipe and an anonymous one.

An anonymous pipe is created by the "pipe()" system call, which returns 2 file descriptors associated with a newly created pipe, one for writing data, the other for reading from it. The shell uses anonymous pipes to connect the standard output of one process to the standard input of another when you connect two process with the "|" operator.

A named pipe appears as a file in the file system, and can be opened with the normal "open()" system call.

In blocking mode (the default), the process that reads from the pipe will block until data appears there; the writer can then send data which will appear as a byte stream to the reader.

The important fact here is that the data that is transferred is a byte stream. The sender and receiver of the data must agree on a protocol to determine how to interpret the bytes. One typical method for this is serialization. Consider a 32 bit integer ... 4 bytes. Some systems store those bytes with the most significant bit in the first byte (known as big-endian), some store the least significant bit in the first byte (little-endian system, such as x86). When transmitting such data across a network, serialization of such data is important, since it is entirely possible that each end stores the data in a different order.

But even when transmitting data between two processes on the same host, serialization helps. It can be used to encapsulate objects so that the receiver knows when it has received everything. For example, with our 32 bit integer, if the receiver doesn't know it is expecting an integer, and gets 3 bytes (the 4th having been delayed by some scheduling), it must know that it needs to wait before continuing.

None of this is particular language specific, save that some languages have built in support for serialization. Java is one such language (see ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream). If you are trying to move data between Java and C programs, and on the Java side you want to use these classes, then you'll need to understand the serialization protocol used by them.

Another common serialization technique is JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), for which there exists several good libraries in C and Java.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really understand the mechanism in transferring data. In the case of pipe method, a conduit will be created between 2 process to transfer byte streams , right?

A named or anonymous pipe is a stream rather like a socket connection over loop back.  In fact in some OSes, it is implemented by the same drivers/library.

> And how about Serialization?

How serialization is done is not a language specific and you can serialize data in a manner which can be shared between C and Java.

> What is the advantages and the disadvantages between them?

There is many forms of serialization and this is too broad a topic to cover in one answer.  You could do an entire thesis on it.

> Can explain one explain to me a very deep mechanism in transferring data of these methods?

There isn't much to it. A block of data is copied to memory managed by the OS and this buffered data can be read by another program (or the same one)

> And are these mechanisms different between Java and C? , or it is the same?

They both use the same OS calls to do the real work.  The Java API hides this fact from you and makes it more Java friendly, but they are the same.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks a lot for your comment. Could you give me one most representative example of the advantage and disadvantage between these 2 methods?

Comment: @xtiger There isn't two methods or even 2000.  I would say there is perhaps 30 common methods. There have relative advantages in terms speed, compatibility, size of message, ease of decoding/encoding, easy of being understood. Each of these forms can be compressed and/or encrypted a number of ways as well, though usual not over a pipe.